# Suspensions from chat with no notice

Tags: support, chat

I was recently suspended on chat with no reason or notice. I would like a mod response to this.

As far as I know the only issue I've had was with a simple,"That's what she said joke". After reading the recent mod posts about what's acceptable in chat, I believe it meets those requirements. It is also something I have both done, and seen done multiple times in chat over the past few months with zero flags raised.

After it was brought to my attention that this joke offended someone, I simply asked it to be deleted.

Your frequent trouble maker, Himarm.

Additional reading, [That's what she said](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/01/thats-what-she-said-the-rise-and-fall-of-the-2000s-best-bad-joke/283259/)

Comment: to be clear, this was a separate suspension from [this one](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7469/5184), right?

Comment: @phantom42 just chat, just happened, for 6 hours :D Though technicly i have no idea if its a separate suspension since i have no idea why i was suspended.

Comment: @phantom42 Yes, this happened about 90 minutes ago

Comment: FWIW, I was also wondering about where the line is here. I've been pretty quick to remind fellow chatters to stay appropriate these last couple days, but I completely glossed over that comment, primarily because I've seen every episode of *The Office* twice. If it's appropriate for prime time public television, is it *really* inappropriate for chat?

Comment: @CreationEdge Different chatrooms have different standards. “That's what she said” is appropriate in some rooms but not in others. Given the current SFF chat situation, err on the side of restraint.

Comment: @Gilles I would err on that side, as well. I'm just trying to gauge what the expectation will be *after* our supervisory period. Part of us remaining successful is helping to keep one another in line and respecting those checks, but we'll need to know what checks to make.

Comment: Why on earth would Blackwood edit this?

Comment: @Axelrod edit points /sigh

Comment: I thought you didn't get points for editing meta...

Comment: @Axelrod meta points?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ArtOfCode put it very well, but I'm chiming in here for the sake of clarity.

*SFF's main chatroom is in an unusual place right now in that it's being guided back to the [Be Nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) standards of the rest of the Stack Exchange network so that the community here can continue to enjoy it.* As such, tolerance for things which fall into gray areas is unusually low over the short term because everyone is finding their footing, and re-establishing baseline standards and behaviors.

Himarm -- it is notable that in comments, you mention that you've made far more polarizing jokes in the past and have received smaller slaps on the wrist. That implies that yes, there's a baseline for normalcy that's been in need of rejiggering for awhile now. By the same token, I'd like to apologize that this did not come with a private, clarifying message right away. Not getting feedback on what's going on is likely to feel strange and unfair, especially since this is a departure from what the community has come to expect.

This suspension is a byproduct of recent events, and is not a personal knock against you in any way. We look forward to having you back in chat in a few hours once the suspension is over.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for, With all the chaos happening, i think its important to accurately let people know exactly what their doing that's wrong or inappropriate.

Comment: @Himarm You got it.

Answer (score 9):

N.B.: I am not the suspending mod, I am merely offering my take on the situation.

I imagine this suspension came along partly as a product of the recent events in SFF chat. Under normal circumstances, perhaps "that's what she said" is par for the course in Mos Eisley - but this can hardly be called "normal circumstances".

At the moment, Mos Eisley Cantina is being... not babysat, but *supervised*. There's a desire to encourage the SFF chat community to conform to similar standards as the rest of the chat network, which is a standard is hasn't always lived up to before. That culminated in the recent events.

I'll quote a message from a SciFi mod:

> Alright, this is what's up. Everyone in Sci-fi & Fantasy.SE chat will be on their utmost best behavior this weekend. If you see problems brewing, help guide your fellow users back on track. Flag things that need a mod or a CM to clean up. We're going to be super-liberal with suspensions, so behave. Be nice, don't gossip, and stay on topic. If additional chat rooms pop up, please do us all a favor and copy this message in there so people are aware.

The Be Nice policy does also make brief reference:

> - **inappropriate language or attention**
>     Avoid vulgar terms or anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.

While SFF chat is being chivvied back to being Nice, it's probably a good idea to refrain from the usual jokes.

Comment: are mod's typically supposed to tell you why you got suspended, or is it regular practice to suspend with no given reason?

Comment: @Himarm in chat, it's 50-50 either way. Sometimes you'll get a warning, *very* occasionally you'll get an email. Sometimes you won't. Suspensions in chat are pretty different from suspensions on the main site, where everything comes with a message.

Comment: Ah, good point that it's right there in the policy, [which was linked to in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25456930#25456930). While I took it as a reference to a TV show, I recognize that it's most likely to be taken as sexual innuendo. That's probably the key here: It's not what any 1 person would perceive it as, but what an average, reasonable person would interpret it as.

Comment: @CreationEdge got it in one. And while normally it'd be OK, in the current state it's best to avoid anything iffy.

Comment: what are average chat suspensions, i made a joke about nuking the middle east and got a 30 min suspension, I do a thats what she said joke and get 6 hours >.>

Comment: @Himarm again, I put that down to current situation. You get 30 minutes if a flag against you is validated, 1 hour if a mod just presses "suspend", or any other length of time if a mod chooses it.